# Is null a type of context?

Tags: android

Why does [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV8BK.jpg) work?

Specifically, why does passing null into a TextView constructor satisfy the argument, just like passing 'super' or 'this' make the code work? Is null a context?

Moreover, does TextView require context to work, like [here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxcej.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this work?

`RuntimeExceptions` are "unchecked" (which is why the code compiles); I would expect that to crash with a `NullPointerException` at some point.

> Is null a context?

`null` has no data type. You can pass `null` for any non-primitive parameter and satisfy the *compiler*. Whether the code will *run* is another matter.

> Moreover, does TextView require context to work, like here?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a beginner programmer and I hope that someday my questions will stop being downvoted. :'(